# Is there a way to tell Resharper 6 to ignore new Async language features?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, resharper, async-ctp

I finally got around to installing the AsyncCtpLibrary.

The 'async' and 'await' keywords are in red and the hover help has the phrases "cannot resolve symbol 'async'", or "cannot resolve symbol 'await'" respectively.

The project AsyncSamplesCS compiles just fine.

Is there a way to tell Resharper to ignore these new Async language features?

Example:

```
    public async void AsyncIntroSingle()
    {
        WriteLinePageTitle(await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://www.weather.gov")));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there's no way to ignore these keywords apart from turning ReSharper code analysis off completely.
We hope to be able to provide initial support of Async and Await in ReSharper 6.1 due this Fall. Here's a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-196518), vote/watch it if you like.

Comment: you can't get more official than that.  btw: Resharper 6 is awesome.  Thanks for making a great product.

Comment: Thank you! ReSharper 6.1 will hopefully get even more awesome

Answer (score 2):

The ReSharper 6.1 Early Access Program is now open. ReSharper 6.1 support async and await keywords — both in C# and VB.NET — and also provides a set of code inspections and quick-fixes: for example, it sees dead code when an asynchronous method lacks await operators, and warns when you’re using a wrong return type in an asynchronous method. More informations here: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/11/resharper-61-eap-opens-much-more-than-a-bugfix-release/